# Read double serialized json file in Python

Tags: python, json, serialization, deserialization

I have a json file which has double serialized. The file has been created as:

```
with open('file.json', 'r') as f:
    file = json.load(f)
#double serializing json file
with open('file_double_serialized.json', "w") as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(json.dumps(file)))
```

How can I read `file_double_serialized.json` in Python and create a normal (single-serialized) json file?

Comment: Is there any error in your code?

Comment: No, I have a file, which has been double serialized with `json.dumps(json.dumps(file))`. So now, I want to read the file and write it as a normal json file with `json.dumps(file)`. How do I read the double-serialized file?

Comment: What happens if you just read this file and do modifications? Does it give you any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reverse the process:

```py
import json

with open('file_double_serialized.json', "r") as f:
    data = json.loads(json.loads(f.read()))

# write correctly
with open('fixed.json','w') as f:
    json.dump(data,f)
```